# Books analysing Norse mythology (specifically Odin)?

Tags: norse, odin

What I am looking for is not a collection of stories and myths per se, but something more general like an analysis/dissection or meta discussion of the myth of Odin and Norse mythology in general. Something like Campbell's "Hero with a thousand faces".

Odin fascinates me by the scale on which he was revered (the guy has over 100 names!) and his character (combining the wisdom/wanderer god and the warrior/leader god aspects). If any of you could provide me with some worthwhile material on this I would be truly grateful!

Comment: I think you'll have better luck getting good answers on this site if you ask specific questions about Odin.

Comment: Your right. That is vague.

Comment: Gods of the Ancient Northmen by Georges Dumezil is available in the archive.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stephan Grundy's *Odhinn the Cult of Death*, and Diana Paxson's *Odin: Ecstasy, Runes, and Norse Practical Magic* are both pretty good, and available on Amazon. If you've already read the *Prose* and *Poetic Edda* you'll have a good grounding in Norse myth generally, these two books will probably answer your questions.